# Why does using `kubectl` with impersonation (`--as=`) result in the error: "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud

Why does using `kubectl` with impersonation `--as=` result in "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused" on a host with only the `default` service account configured?

I have downloaded `kubectl` to a host with only the `default` service account configured. If I try to impersonate any user, e.g. `system:anonymous`, the following error message is returned: "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused".

I can resolve the issue by starting a local proxy using `kubectl proxy --port=8080`, however, I would like to avoid this.

Why does `kubectl` try to connect to `localhost:8080`, when using impersonation (`--as=`)?

```
kube@ctf1-k8s-deploy1-545977f47-g9dpl:~$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
kube@ctf1-k8s-deploy1-545977f47-g9dpl:~$ ls /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/
ca.crt  namespace  token
kube@ctf1-k8s-deploy1-545977f47-g9dpl:~$ kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:anonymous
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clusters` need to have the host and port of the Kubernetes API Server.

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://API_SERVER_HOST:PORT
```

Edit:

When `--as` is added as parameter to `kubectl auth can-i` then kubectl is not using in-cluster configuration any more which is why its referring to localhost:8080 instead of correct API Server IP.

Comment: But, API server information is available in environment variables: `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT` etc. I guess that's why `kubectl` is working correctly, when not using the `--as` impersonation option using `default` service account? Why is it necessary to configure `clusters` for impersonation, when not needed for `default` service account?

Comment: are you doing this inside a pod?

Comment: Exactly, I'm doing this inside a pod :-)

Comment: when we add --as its not using in-cluster configuration anymore... It seems to me a bug rather than an expected behavior

Comment: What exactly is the in-cluster configuration? Is it the `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` and `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT` together with `default` service account?

Comment: Where does `kubectl` get the namespace from? I don't see it in any environment variable, not in the `default` service account's directory?

Comment: there is namespace in /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the `kubectl` has an issue where any client configuration override flag (eg. --as, --request-timeout,...) disables the automatic fallback to in-cluster configuration.

See Kubernetes [Github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93474)